# Last Non-blank Column In A Row

Tags: excel, formulas, excel-indirect

I've found the following formula which works great when you are searching within the same sheet in Excel. So this formula works when I want excel to return the last value in row 3.

```
 ={INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,MAX((3:3<>"")*COLUMN(3:3)),1))}
```

I'm struggling to use it when I want excel to return the last value in row 3 of a different worksheet. Can anyone help?

Thanks
RP

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for INDIRECT in this case.

For working with different worksheets, you have to refer the worksheet within the cell addresses.

```
{=INDEX(Sheet1!3:3,,MAX((Sheet1!3:3<>"")*COLUMN(Sheet1!3:3)))}
```

Without using array formulas the same could be achieved with:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!3:3,,LOOKUP(2,1/(Sheet1!3:3<>""),COLUMN(Sheet1!3:3)))
```

But this is basing on a strange not really documented behavior of LOOKUP which takes {1; #DIV/0; 1; 1; #DIV/0} as a sorted array.

The INDEX variants return a cell reference. So we can build dynamic ranges like:

```
Sheet1!A3:INDEX(Sheet1!3:3,,LOOKUP(2,1/(Sheet1!3:3<>""),COLUMN(Sheet1!3:3)))
```

If you are only interested in the last value

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(Sheet1!3:3<>""),Sheet1!3:3)
```

will also suffice. But this returns the value only, not the reference.

Pro and cons for the array formula in this case:

pro: It works like it is documented. (Sheet1!3:3<>"") returns TRUE or FALSE and TRUE * COLUMN(Sheet1!3:3) gets COLUMN(Sheet1!3:3) while FALSE * COLUMN(Sheet1!3:3) gets 0. So the MAX then is the biggest column number where (Sheet1!3:3<>"").

con: It is slow. Not unusable in this case, because we work only on all cells in a row. But if we would apply this on all cells in a column, then it would be unusable slow.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Is there a way to get the same result without the need for an array formula?

Comment: Thanks! Which one would you use on balance? What are the main pros and cons of array formulas?

Comment: I can't write about pro and cons for array formulas in general. This would be too broad. But for this case, see my supplement again.

Comment: The INDEX is superfluous in the LOOKUP version. Simply: =LOOKUP(2,1/(Sheet1!3:3<>""),Sheet1!3:3) will suffice.

Comment: @XOR LX: Right in the case you will not need the cell reference but the value only.